# Fastest way to check if a number is divisible by another in python

Tags: python, division

I’ve been doing something with primes in python, and I’m currently using this

```
def isDivisible(number,divisor):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

to check if a number is divisible by the divisor.
So I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this?

Comment: The python modulo operator is quiet fast. If you want to speed this up even further removing the extra function call and if condition can help. See Dominique's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52773970/3419728)

Comment: Any waste of time will most likely be above this routine. e. g. by calling it too often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
return (number % divisor == 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

A speed test shows that checking `not()` is faster than a `!= 0` solution:

```
%%timeit 
not(8 % 3)
# 19 ns ± 0.925 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%%timeit 
8 % 3 != 0
# 27.1 ns ± 0.929 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Don't you mean to use `8 % 3 == 0` in the second example instead of `8 % 3 != 0` ?  I tested both on my machine, and found that the `== 0` version was marginally faster than the `!= 0` version.  (Of course, your mileage may vary.)

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is a "faster" way of checking this. And it seems pretty simple. However, I would write your function as:

```
def isDivisible(number, divisor):
    return number % divisor == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Not faster, but note that `number % divisor == 0` already returns a boolean. So you could simply do:

```
is_divisible = lambda number, divisor: number % divisor == 0
```

to define your function. This however is still the same method you are using. Could be marginally faster, I haven't tested.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use `lambda`:

```
isDivisible = lambda x,y: x%y==0

isDivisible(4,2)
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: Not convincingly better than AGNGazers standard function definition.