# Is there a way of checking if a value is evenly divisible by any value in a given data set?

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to write a simple bit of python 3 code that allows the user to tell the program which prime number it wants to find and then return the number to the user. I have hit a roadblock because I need to check if the "newprime" value is in fact a prime, which requires me to divide the value by all the previous prime numbers ("primes") and then checking if the answer is a whole number or not. Here is the current program

```
import numpy

primes = [2]

print("the how many-th prime would you like to calculate?")

numberOfPrime = int( input() )

x = 0
while x <= numberOfPrime:
  notprime = 0 #placeholder, should be all numbers which when divided by any of the set "primes" gives a whole number
  while newprime == notprime:
    newprime = primes[x] + 1

  primes.append(newprime)
  print(primes)
  x += 1

print(primes[numberOfPrime], " is the ", numberOfPrime, "-th prime number", sep="")
```

As you can see, I added a comment where I would have to insert the missing part.
How do I best approach this?

Comment: The easy, direct way of finding primes within a range (up to a certain size) is to use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It'll also allow you to track the factors of a number by having a list in each index of the numbers that "visited" it. However, for larger `n`-s it becomes unusable because of memory requirements, but for what you want to achieve here it should work fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a number is divisible by another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773914/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-in-python)