# noob horribly stuck on what is most likely an easy question

Tags: python-3.x

[Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT2E2.jpg)

Trying to create a password generator

Cannot get if statement to work correctly, or know if this is really the right way to approach the problem. I need it to divide each letters number representation by 3 and return a # if it is a whole number.

```
password = input("password: ")
password = password.lower()
output = []
for character in password:
  number = ord(character) - 96
  output.append(number)

x = output
if x / 3:
  print ("#")

  print (output)
```

I get this error:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: welcome to the community. first up, dont say you need help with an assignment because this is not homework help community. dont say thanks and all that. not required. Lastly, as of now, the question is poorly formed. try and look at other questions and learn. put relevant code blocks or full code, and make sure you have a error or unexpected output which will make the question focused. right now, this is just a poorly written question.

Comment: instead of asking whole program's error, you can try to solve exception first. For math problems, try draw out a graph to make logic clear.

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: x is a list. You are trying to divide the list by 3. What are you planning to do? Are you planning to divide [1,2,3] /3 ?

Comment: What do you expect `x / 3` to do?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I was attempting to divide each number individually in the list by three to find and replace ones that are answered in whole numbers with a # and leave the rest of the numbers alone.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am very new to Python and my thinking was that by defining x=output that I could then begin to work on if statements to divide the contents by 3 to find and replace numbers wholly divisible by 3 with a # and all other to remain un-touched.

Comment: In that case you would want to [**loop** over the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) (`output`) and check each element individually. Division on lists is not defined. Then, for each number you [check if it's divisible by 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773914/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do with the divisible by 3. To get you started, here's an example code. See if this helps you get started in the right direction.

```
password = input('enter password :').lower()
output = []
for c in password:
    num = ord(c) - 96
    output.append(num)

all_div_by_3 = True
for i in output:
    if i%3 != 0:  #checks if remainder of i/3 is zero. if zero, then divisible, else not divisible.
        all_div_by_3 = False
        break

if all_div_by_3: #is same as if all_div_by_3 == True:
    print ('all divisible by 3')
else:
    print ('all characters are not divisible by 3')
```

The output from this are as follows:

```
enter password :cliff
all divisible by 3

enter password :rock
all characters are not divisible by 3
```

Answer (score 0):

After much reading and research through here it became apparent I needed to use the if, elif, and else functions. below is the completed project.

```
password = input("password: ") 
password = password.lower()
output = []
for character in password:
 number = ord(character) - 96
 output.append(number)
for i in output:
 if(i% 3 == 0) :
  print('#', end ="")
 elif(i% 5 == 0) :
  print('%', end ="") 
 else:
  print(chr(i+98), end="")
```